# what is the modulepreloaded js in vite multiple page build

Tags: reactjs, vite

I faced with this question when I tried to create a multi-page React application using vite.

My vite setup looks like this:

vite.config.ts

```js
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        page1: resolve(__dirname, 'page1.html'),
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: 'assets/javascript/[name].js',
        assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].[ext]';
        },
      },
    },
```

Then, the output result of the build is as follows:

```
../../dist/index.html                    0.57 kB │ gzip:  0.33 kB
../../dist/page1.html                    0.64 kB │ gzip:  0.34 kB
../../dist/assets/index.css              0.00 kB │ gzip:  0.02 kB
../../dist/assets/javascript/page1.js    0.24 kB │ gzip:  0.21 kB
../../dist/assets/javascript/main.js    23.86 kB │ gzip:  5.88 kB
../../dist/assets/client-34c92d06.js   142.43 kB │ gzip: 45.71 kB
```

Here is the question of what is the client-34c92d06.js that did not appear at the time of the SPA.

I only need the js output on each page(ex. page1.js), and it appears to be working fine if I remove the statement that loads this js in the HTML of each page currently:

page1.html

```html
...
 <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/javascript/page1.js"></script>
 <!-- <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/assets/client-34c92d06.js"> -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.css">
...
```